# How to update nvd3 chart with new data

Tags: nvd3.js

There is `nvd3` code that creates the charts, for instance:

https://github.com/novus/nvd3/blob/master/examples/scatterChart.html

But how to just update the already created chart with new data? I tried to just run

```
        d3.select(node)
            .datum(data_func)
            .call(chart)
```

Thinking that `nv.addChart()` is adding the chart, but the code above actually added new chart without removing the previous one.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

> Update

I figured out that `d3.select(node).datum(data_func);` is updating the data for the chart. So, if I call it and then resize the window, the data is updated without chart being redrawn. Now I do not know which function to call to update it automatically.

Answer (score 0):

So, the solution was just to use a global variable for `chart` and call the code:

```
       d3.select(node)
        .datum(data_func);
       chart.update();
```